# подключение log4j в java ee

Tags: java-ee, log4j

Хочу подключить log4j в java ee но никак не получается реализовать, не понимаю в чем проблема или вообще изначально не правильно настраиваю логирование

Через maven подключаю библиотеку в pom.xml добавляю log4j

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

log4j.xml находится в resourse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'
                     debug="true">

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5KB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="4"/>
        <param name="file" value="loggi/logfileDAO.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="ru.dmitriykotyshov.DAO">
        <!--all, trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal-->
        <priority value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </category>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Начинаю писать логи и появляется ошибка

```
log4j:ERROR Could not parse url [file:/C:/Users/Дмитрий/IdeaProjects/projectTrainTicket/out/artifacts/projectTrainTicket/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml].
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI$MalformedURIException: Path contains invalid character: Д
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.initializePath(URI.java:1109)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.initialize(URI.java:582)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.<init>(URI.java:335)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.URI.<init>(URI.java:298)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.expandSystemIdStrictOff1(XMLEntityManager.java:2221)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.expandSystemId(XMLEntityManager.java:2053)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:968)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1152)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$2.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:769)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:871)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    at ru.dmitriykotyshov.GetRoute.<clinit>(GetRoute.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2555)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2544)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ru.dmitriykotyshov.GetRoute).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Как это можно исправить или вообще как подключить логи в java ee?

Comment: Xerces ругается на путь, который содержит не ASCII символы... Можно, или разбираться в чем проблема в Xerces, или перенести в директорию с путём, несодержащим русских символов, или просто использовать log4j.properties файл, по старинке.

Comment: @Sergi а есть хороший туториал по log4j.properties?

Comment: на русском, к сожалению, не знаю. Вообще, сейчас уже есть [Log4J 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

Comment: @Sergi можно и на английском, главное что хороший

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал xml на property и все заработало, видимо на tomcat возникает какая то проблема с url к xml файлу, если там имеются символы кириллицы, если кто то в курсе этой проблемы дополните ответ

```
#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=All, stdout, file

#Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t]: %m%n

#Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log/app.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t]: %m%n
```